# Must I have a Mac OS platform even if I develop my app with PhoneGap?

Tags: asp.net, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I had a Web Application written on Visual Studio (C#) and I want to create mobile applications for iOS and Android.

Do I have to get a Mac OS platform (e.g. a MacBook) to develop an iOS application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. To be able to publish your ios app to the appstore, you do need a machine with a Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

In order to develop for iOS, you need to use Xcode, which is a Mac-exclusive piece of software. So unless you emulate a Mac environment on windows, you need to get a mac. PhoneGap is simply an API for the iOS platform (a great one, too!), and it would be in addition to the built-in iOS frameworks. From what I can tell from your question, you are simply asking about how to develop on iOS. It's a great process, and there are plenty of great books to get you started with iOS.

However, to answer your question, yes. In order to develop for iOS, you need a Mac environment.